# My monitor's resolution keeps defaulting to the lowest possible after driver update, sleeping the PC or "reconnecting"; in general after short time

Tags: windows-10, drivers, multiple-monitors, sleep, screenresolution

My monitor keeps reverting to the lowest supported resolution.

This problem usually occurs after installing driver updates, however, it can also happen when the PC has been has been sleeping for more than 5-10 minutes (sometimes even less).

Early on, I would restore the proper resolution by shutting down the PC and waiting a few minutes before turning it back on.  These days, I can recreate the problem, and/or resolve it, by disconnecting the display's power cable and then reconnecting it after a delay of about 5 minutes.

I've found some people sharing similar problems on other forums:

- Tom's Hardware: [DisplayPort issues with the AOC G2460PF](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/displayport-issues-with-the-aoc-g2460pf.3300530/)
- How To Geek: [4 Common DisplayPort Problems, and How to Fix Them](https://www.howtogeek.com/813778/how-to-fix-common-displayport-problems/)

These guys and others seem to have had similar "No Signal" issues, but mine just seems way more irritating and random. Some have managed to fix the problem with another DisplayPort cable.  I haven't tried this yet as I don't have a second DP cable and live far from any store that sells them.  I may try to get one when I am next in the city. While the frequency of my problem sometimes varies from the other people whose posts I have found, the posts share a similarity in the model of AOC display.

###### Additional Details:

- Dual monitors:

  - [AOC G2460PF](https://eu.aoc.com/en/gaming/products/monitors/g2460pf) (2016) - via DisplayPort
  - [ASUS VK222H](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/aoc-g2460pf-24-inch-144hz-freesync-monitor,4743.html) (2008) - via HDMI
    *(the built-in webcam stopped working in 2015)*
- GPU: Nvidia Geforce GTX 3060 TI (Gigabyte)
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 3700X
- Motherboard: MSI MPG x570x GAMING PLUS 2.0
- OS: Windows 10 Home

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The usual 'fix' for this issue is to manually 'wake' the screen before the computer. It's not fast enough to register correctly as the computer wakes, so it is just sent a lowest common denominator resolution.

Comment: That's useful, but not an actual fix sadly.

Comment: @Paradonas, the articles you linked were about  "No Signal" issues over DP, but your question is about the *"lowest resolution possible"*.  Can you clarify if this is simply an issue with translation and you are actually experiencing a "no signal" issue (blank display) like ther other posts, or is your display in fact reverting to a lower resolution?

Comment: @BlindSpots Yes, kind off. The problem isn't receiving a "no signal" message but it is still relevant since I do receive a "no signal" message every time my monitor is disconnected. When my monitor disconnects and I receive a "no signal" message I disconnect it from the power outlet and reconnect it. Then the screen turns on like it should except the resolution is low. I think this is the same type of message they receive when they mention they get a "no signal" message. I thought that maybe the issue could be similar to theirs and might be resolved by buying a new DisplayPort cable.

Comment: If the DP cable came with the display it is "likely" okay but who knows.  You will need to try different things on your end.   I suggested [some things you can try](https://superuser.com/a/1784602/)  In addition, I think your GPU has 3 x DP ports so you can try different ones, and look at the resolution and refresh rate you are using and try variations.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you can try.  Don't make multiple changes at the same time.  Try one then wait to see if the problem reoccurs.

## 1

This article you linked: [Display Adapter Link Failure](https://www.howtogeek.com/813778/how-to-fix-common-displayport-problems/#:%7E:text=Good%20DisplayPort%20Cable-,Display%20Adapter%20Link%20Failure,-The%20first%20clue) seems to speak directly to your problem.

They suggested as a troubleshooting step: [Disable DisplayPort 1.2](https://www.howtogeek.com/813778/how-to-fix-common-displayport-problems/#autotoc_anchor_2:%7E:text=fix%20the%20problem.-,Disable%20DisplayPort%201.2,-This%20problem%20seems) which seems possible with your display.

Download [AOC G2460PF User Manual](https://eu.aoc.com/en/gaming/products/monitors/g2460pf/downloads) and see page 33, "OSD Setup > DP Capability" (typo "Capaciliby" in English manual). See image: [image]

## 2

[Test another DP cable](https://www.howtogeek.com/813778/how-to-fix-common-displayport-problems/#:%7E:text=we%20explored%20earlier.-,Plan%20Ahead%3A%20Choosing%20a%20Good%20DisplayPort%20Cable,-Several%20of%20the)

## 3

Depending on what monitor drivers you have currently installed, you can,

- Install AOC's Official monitor driver
- Install AOC's Beta driver (35-146Hz range)
- Remove AOC drivers and test with generic Windows display drivers

[Download AOC G2460PF Drivers (2015)](https://eu.aoc.com/api/frontberg/downloadable/6018464a-5906-497e-b2f7-8d53f6b5501d/Windows_Drivers_G2460PF.zip) - package includes Official & Beta drivers

## 4

Your display also has power management software "AOC e-Saver", If it is installed, uninstall it. (page 48, in the manual)
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I've actually found the best solution already and will post it shortly. This however is definetly much faster and easier than unplugging the DisplayPort cable and then re-attaching it after a short(er delay than re-pluggin the powercable after 5min which I also found out). No definitive solution seems available though, only temporary ones. This one is no hassle really.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution which would be to install the graphics drivers supplied discretely in the manual for this thing. That didn't fix it, but it's the best I've got.
Although I found some quicker temporary solutions like re-plugging the DisplayPort cable only need a delay of about 10 seconds or until the "no signal" message disappears. You can also go into the OSD settings on your screen and change DisplayPort version to fix it even quicker sometimes. Not if it wasn't working previously however, then this doesn't work.

I guess the only solution would be to contact AOC which I doubt I'll do since duh. Maybe we need some establish some DisplayPort standards here to make sure this doesn't happen already at the production line or something.
Until then, maybe I'll get a new DisplayPort cable and it will work.

Comment: This is the link that helped me and actually encountering the problem again as well as bothering to research it when it happened. I took some photos but don't think they are necessary to post. [Binary Fork Failsafe NV Monitor](https://binaryfork.com/nvidia-nv-failsafe-monitor-detected-9517/)

Comment: If it didn't work, it's not a solution. This should be and edit of the question.